# Block Trades for stocks

Tags: stocks, futures

Which organization reports block trades for futures and options? There are a lot of webpages which report block trades but what is the organization which is tasked with reporting block transaction?

I ask this because there are websites which are selling this data. I am curious where are they getting the data from in the first place. Because this data has to free as it is material information which will influence price.

Comment: Could it be the Exchanges themselves?

Comment: I have been looking at CME website for a while but have not been able to find where these bulk deals posted realtime

Comment: A block trade can be executed all at once or in pieces.  If negotiated off exchange then it has to be reported to the exchange which then provides  the details (price, volume).

Comment: @newcoder I wouldn't expose high volume info on a website available to the wide public.  Performance would be a dog.  There might be an API only available to brokerages, news agencies (Bloomberg, Yahoo, and the like), etc.

Comment: @RonJohn Stock Ticker is high volume information, block trades actually happen at a much lower frequency because they are high volume trades, which gets reported the next day after the transaction so they are not that high volume. :)

Comment: The brokers are responsible for reporting them to the various exchanges, however, because they are not reported in real time they appear outside the actual order of events.  In other words, the items on the ticker are not in the historical order if a block trade is involved.  Nor the dollar amounts correct because they report the weighted average.  That means high, low, open and close can be incorrect.

Comment: I would expect it to be the exchanges. I don't believe that they are required to create a feed for public use on their website, but via information dissemination organizations (bloomberg etc) is sufficiently "public".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misperception among those who perform analysis of items on the ticker that it is a historical record of events as they happened.  That is only true for some small trades.  If small trades make up a block trade, then they never appear as separate items.  Block trades that complete in the day are reported by brokers to the exchanges after the event.  I cannot comment on the current rules for trades that complete across days as I have not read the regulations for some years.  There is no way for an outsider to get access to events as they happened.  Also, certain things regarding options are restricted to the dealers and the staff of the SEC.  Except for a court proceeding where you are a target, you are not going to get it under any circumstance.

Comment: I know you cannot get this data immediately but your are required to report this within 24 hrs thus after reporting this data, where does it become available. Since this data is being sold!

Comment: You can buy it from services like CRSP, however, the block trades are still not reported as they happen.  They are inserted after completion but not necessarily at completion

Comment: I understand I will not get dark pool data as they happen becuase they defeat the purpose of dark pools. I just want to know which organization is responsible to disseminating that data the next day for US stock market!

Comment: The exchanges disseminate it.

Comment: I would also add, that if you listen to the trades feed for futures and add up all the trade volumes for a day, and then compare that to the reported trade volume on a daily feed, then the former can be quite a bit less than the later. A fact that my senior execution algo specialist thought was impossible... the difference was the later reported dark pool and block trades.